# Need help dealing with a DLL error based on matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, dll, dllimport

Here is my basic program I am running with a local jupyter notebook on my computer. I am not sure how to resolve this dll error:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib as mpl
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline
```

Here is the error message accompanying my code:

```
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-1-c1680853bc3a> in <module>()
          1 import numpy as np
          2 import matplotlib as mpl
    ----> 3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
          4 #%matplotlib inline

    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>()
         29 from cycler import cycler
         30 import matplotlib
    ---> 31 import matplotlib.colorbar
         32 from matplotlib import style
         33 from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive

    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py in <module>()
         30 
         31 import matplotlib as mpl
    ---> 32 import matplotlib.artist as martist
         33 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
         34 import matplotlib.collections as collections

    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in <module>()
         14 import matplotlib
         15 from . import cbook, docstring, rcParams
    ---> 16 from .path import Path
         17 from .transforms import (Bbox, IdentityTransform, Transform,     TransformedBbox,
         18                          TransformedPatchPath, TransformedPath)

    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py in <module>()
         19 import numpy as np
         20 
    ---> 21 from . import _path, rcParams
         22 from .cbook import (_to_unmasked_float_array, simple_linear_interpolation,
         23                     maxdict)

    ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: Something went wrong when installing matplotlib. This may happen if you use non-matching versions of numpy and matplotlib or if you install a 64bit version on a 32 bit system or vice versa. The clean solution would be to uninstall numpy and matplotlib and reinstall the correct versions.

Comment: So where would i download those packages, because typically I'm running a pip install to retrieve those modules

Comment: Using pip *should* work fine. If it doesn't, there are some prebuilt libraries on https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/